# How do I move out of the first if statement when user enters 1?

Tags: python-3.x

```
user_input = input(menu).strip().lower()
#This program reads student names and grades
while True:#FIXME
    if user_input == '1':#FIXME incorrect output
         name,grades = input(prompt).split()#Add key and value to dict
         student_grades[name] = grades
         print(name)
    elif user_input == '2':#delete name from dict
         del_name = input('Enter name to delete: ')
         del student_grades[del_name]
    elif user_input == '3': #print names and grades
         for key, value in student_grades.iteritems():
             print(key, value)
    elif user_input == '4':
         break
    else:
         print('Unkown Command')
         break
```

Comment: with `break`, just like you did in the `elif` blocks. You may however meant to put `input()` inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are stuck in the first conditional `if` statement is caused by a logical error in your code. You asked for and got user input equal to '1' and afterward started an infinite `while` loop. In this while loop you no longer ask for user input, therefore it is always equal to '1' and you are constantly running the content of the first `if` statement. To fix move the first line asking for user input into the while loop. Like so:

```
#This program reads student names and grades
while True:#FIXME
    user_input = input(menu).strip().lower()
    if user_input == '1':#FIXME incorrect output
    [...]
```